# How to display something conditionally in template file depending on the current path

Tags: 6, theming, users

I would like to do  on page.tpl.php conditionally depending on the current path. I'm using [Auto Assign Role](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) and have two paths for registration.

Reading [this tutorial](http://11heavens.com/theming-the-register-form-in-Drupal-6), as far as I've understood I can make a template file that overrides the registration page. However I would like to display different things on two deferent paths. How can I do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to change and why you want to do that. Has it to do with registration functionality or is it about design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just test the current URL with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/registration-page-1') : ?>
<p>Display something.</p>
<?php elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/registration-page-2') : ?> 
<p>Display something else.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It's not exactly an elegant solution (there are better, more structured ways) but it will do in a pinch.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Thanks for this simple solution. It's easy enough to understand for me and works for my need.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal core's template suggestions allow for naming page templates [based on the path of the page](http://drupal.org/node/1089656#page-suggestion). So, theoretically, if you had www.mysite.com/registration-a, then you could use the the page template name page--registration-a.tpl.php and so forth.

However, if this does not work, you can create a page preprocess function in your theme or module that adds some [template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/223440) based on the path.  For example:

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

 if($arg[0] == 'registration-a'){
 $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] =  'page__registration_a';
 }

 if($arg[0] == 'registration-b'){
 $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] =  'page__registration_b';
 }

}
```

this would allow you to use page--registration-a.tpl.php and page--registration-b.tpl.php, etc.

For reference, $arg is an array that contains the different parts of a URL, so if you had the path mysite.com/registration/customer, then `$arg[0]` would be 'registration' and `$arg[1]` would be 'customer'.

Answer (score 1):

Use the hook_theme() function. So  you can display two types of templates for two types of URLs. Here is the example.

```
function MODULENAME_theme() {
  return array(
    'theme_name_1' => array(
      'arguments' => array('param' => NULL),      
      'template' => 'TEMPLATE_NAME_1',
      ),
          'theme_name_2' => array(
      'arguments' => array('param' => NULL),      
      'template' => 'TEMPLATE_NAME_2',
      ),      
    );
}

function MODULENAME_menu() {
    $items = array();   
    //Link to the test_module admin page:
    $items['URL1'] = array(
        'title' => 'Test Module',        
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('advance_test_form'),        
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    $items['URL1'] = array(
        'title' => t('Test Module test template'),        
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('advance_test_form'),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,        
    );

  return $items;
}
```

If the form having the same fields use single call back function and call the theme depends on URL. If form fields are different, use two different call back functions.

Using themes the code is the following one:

```
return theme('TEMPLATE_NAME_1',$var);
```